# How can I get a top level coverage report for ALL my projects?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

Asked support forum but they are unresponsive: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-can-i-get-a-top-level-coverage-report-for-all-my-projects/30286

I was looking in the UI and googling but didnt turn anything up

I have 2 teams in bitbucket and many projects in each

I just want to generate a csv that includes each sonar project name and the current code coverage of that project

How do I do this? Can I export this csv/pdf/whatever report that includes projects in both of my organizations?

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube comes with two awesome functionality to group projects under a application (in your case say team).

The two functionality are:

1. [Applications](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/applications/#:%7E:text=An%20Application%20is%20an%20aggregation%20of%20projects%20into%20a%20synthetic%20project.&text=With%20an%20Application%2C%20they%20can,and%20most%20importantly%3A%20Quality%20Gate) : An Application is an aggregation of projects into a synthetic project.
2. [Portfolios](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/portfolios/) : Portfolio offers an aggregate view of the releasability of all projects in the Portfolio.

> Note: Both of these two available in Sonarqube Enterprise Edition only.

Comment: I use sonarcloud is it for sonarcloud? because otherwise I cant use it. Also I dont see how portfolios or applications allow for the report I want